# How can i put json result into an input value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django

I am trying to put json result into a input the value.

I have this code:

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:  '{% url "url_searchTour"%}', 
   data: data1,
   success: function(jsonAjaxResult){  
            console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonAjaxResult));
            $('#txt_nombre').val(jsonAjaxResult);


   },
   error: function(data){
   alert("Got an error, Pleas conctact the Administrator");

                                }

                        });
```

The view returns single json object.

View:

```
    dataSer1 = serializers.serialize("json",dataT1)
    dataSer2 = serializers.serialize("json",dataT2)
    data0 = json.dumps({'dataEsp':dataSer1,'dataEng':dataSer2})
return HttpResponse(data0, content_type='application/json')
```

How can I put the information returned into a inputy value. For example like this:

```
$('#txt_nombre').val(jsonAjaxResult['dataEsp.name']); //from obj1
 $('#txt2_nombre').val(jsonAjaxResult['dataEng.name']); //from obj2
```

What i have so far is this:

`console.log(jsonAjaxResult['dataEsp']);`

It retuns the next code:

```
[{
"fields":
 {
 "Monday": true, 
 "restrictions": "No kids",
 "name": "Yate Mar", 

 }, 
 "model": "appMain.touresp", 
 "pk": 1
 }]
```

Comment: You can set the actual JSON string returned, or if you want to pass a javascript object as JSON, you can use `JSON.stringify`

Comment: What i have so far is this

 `console.log(jsonAjaxResult['dataEsp']);`

it retuns the next code:

    [{
    "fields":
     {
     "Monday": true, 
     "restrictions": "No kids",
     "name": "Yate Mar", 
    
     }, 
     "model": "appMain.touresp", 
     "pk": 1
     }]

Comment: Then try this `JSON.stringify(jsonAjaxResult['dataEsp.name'])`

Comment: if i put that, the console says that is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**JSON.stringify()** it's the way to do it, check how it's working with your data.

```js
var jsonData = [{
"fields":
 {
 "Monday": true, 
 "restrictions": "No kids",
 "name": "Yate Mar", 

 }, 
 "model": "appMain.touresp", 
 "pk": 1
 }]

console.log(jsonData)

var txt = document.getElementById("myTxt");
txt.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(jsonData)
```

```html
<textarea id="myTxt"></textarea>
```